# Are URLs UTF-8 encoded?

Tags: 8, uri

I want to use special characters (like üßä) in my clean URL alias's and [google says they must be UTF8 encoded](https://webmasters.googleblog.com/2010/03/working-with-multilingual-websites.html).

I have no idea if this is the case by default, or how to check. Are URLs UTF-8 encoded?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything in Drupal is UTF-8 encoded, yes.

Be aware that various tools still don't properly support such characters in URLs and might display it encoded.